# Web scraping using GCP dataflow in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to do web scraping using dataflow using python SDK. I tried Cloud function to do web scraping but it has timeout limitation of 9 mins. Here web scraping will take more than 30 min.
Any one help me on how to do web scraping using dataflow in python. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have some specific reason for using Dataflow? Why dont you use a VM instance?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to do? Dataflow allows you to write arbitrary code in DoFns, so fetching http content is straightforward, but overall pipeline will also depend on how you are getting the urls to scrape and where you want to put the results.